# Xamarin C# - IMKAnnotation does not contain a definition for 'x'

Tags: c#, object, xamarin, definition

My `MKAnnotation annotation` object has a variable called `IsEmergency`, but when I run this code:

```
 if (annotation.IsEmergency == "0")
        {
            //doStuff();
        }
```

I receive an error that my `annotation` object does not contain a definition for `IsEmergency`.

[image]

In the screenshot I've provided you can see that my object contains this variable.

Here is the full error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'IMKAnnotation' does not contain a definition for 'IsEmergency' and no extension method 'IsEmergency' accepting a first argument of type 'IMKAnnotation' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)       270 Active
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That map delegate method is begin passed an `IMKAnnotation`, so cast it to your MKAnnotation subclass:

```
var myAnnotation = annotation as `YourMKAnnotationSubClass`;
if (myAnnotation?.IsEmergency == "0")
{
    //doStuff();
}
```

Comment: SushiHangover once again to the rescue!